# unexpected indent for python timeit

Tags: python, timeit

I have a problem with doing timeit for python.
Here is codes

```
 import timeit
>>> iteration_test = """
     for i in itr :
         pass
         """
>>> 
>>> timeit.timeit(iteration_test, setup='itr = list(range(10000))', number=1000)
```

I tried tab solution but it didn't work.
What is the problem?

Comment: If your code really looks exactly like that, the problem is that your `for` loop is indented.  It should not be indented.

Comment: """ is opened and closed for text records but you are using it in for loop that was the issue

Comment: There is a duplicate with a good explanation: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23666307/timeit-module-in-python-does-not-run-correctly

Answer (score 1):

write your code like this -

```
iteration_test = """ 
for i in itr : 
    pass 
"""

timeit.timeit(iteration_test, setup='itr = list(range(10000))', number=1000)
```

Comment: It matters because now no error. Python's triple quote strings starts from global scope even though it is written under a function

Comment: @Sujay, have you tried the code. It works fine. 3 quoted strings also takes in indentation. Unlike single quotes or double which ignores initial indentation

Comment: @Sujay Indentations do matter in strings, when the string contains Python code that is supposed to be correct. As PCM says, try it.

Answer (score 1):

You entered a tab at the begining of your for statement.
Try this:

```py
    import timeit
    
    iteration_test = """for i in itr : pass """
    
    timeit.timeit(iteration_test, setup='itr = list(range(10000))', number=1000)
```

Answer (score 0):

space in the three quotes(multiline string) are considered part of the string.
[python multi line strings](https://www.w3schools.com/python/gloss_python_multi_line_strings.asp) even if the variable name has space before it the string should not have spaces in it. it may not look correct in first view but logically it makes sense

for example...

```
  iteration_test = """
for i in itr:
  pass
"""
```